# understanding "Layout run failure" error logging

Tags: debugging, logging, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am doing some charting work and got a single line message "Layout run failure" when nothing was being created on the chart. Looking into this I found that I have to add some additional script files to generate the log files as covered [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/release-notes.html):

> Layout Failures
>
> As result of the design for the layout engine in 4.1, it is possible
>   for improper configuration (or a bug) to cause a layout run to fail to
>   complete all of its calculations. When this occurs, the layout simply
>   stops and the partial results that have been flushed to the DOM are
>   all that is visible. In some cases, the layout may be 99% complete and
>   the failure may go undetected or appear as a minor visual anomaly. In
>   other cases, the layout may fail early and leave the UI in a clearly
>   broken state (much like a JS error during layout would do in previous
>   versions).
>
> Diagnostics
>
> The first step if you suspect you are seeing a layout failure is to
>   enable the layout diagnostics. This is done by replacing the normal
>   "ext-all.js" file with "ext-all-dev.js" and adding a couple additional
>   scripts.

I added the required scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/src/diag/layout/Context.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/src/diag/layout/ContextItem.js"></script>
```

And now I get diagnostic data that I can't make any sense of - it doesn't seem to diagnose an error:

```
++printer<autocontainer> - size: configured/shrinkWrap
    --statprint-1472<autocontainer> - size: configured/configured
        triggeredBy: count=1
            statprint-1472.containerChildrenDone:dom () dirty: false, setBy: ?
        --chart-1473<draw> - size: shrinkWrap/shrinkWrap
            triggeredBy: count=1
                chart-1473.containerChildrenDone:dom (true) dirty: false, setBy: ?
    ++panel-1474<dock> - boxParent: printer - size: natural/configured
    ++panel-1474<autocontainer> - boxParent: printer - size: natural/configured
    ++statprint-1472<dock> - size: configured/configured
        ++statprint-1472_header<body> [isBoxParent] - size: calculated/shrinkWrap
        ++statprint-1472_header<hbox> [isBoxParent] - size: calculated/shrinkWrap
            ++statprint-1472_header_hd<autocomponent> [isBoxParent] - size: calculated/shrinkWrap
            ++tool-1475<autocomponent> [isBoxParent] - size: configured/configured
```

Does any one know where the diagnostic information is explained?

Comment: Short answer is, it's rather complicated. If you could post a test case (as simple as possible) I can try and and help out.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I'll post a new question with the problem that led me into trying to diagnose "Layout run failure".

Comment: I'm interested can you put a reference link to the question here

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11545837/1062992) was the question

Comment: I'm getting the same issue when I mix 'border' and 'vbox' layout.  I'm setting 'border' in my viewport which extends 'Ext.container.Viewport', and I have a child (within the 'items' config) in this Viewport view with 'vbox' layout containing two child items.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find these types of errors are often solved the quickest with a comment-out-till-it-goes-away approach to isolating which component config is causing the layout failure. Comment out child components from the inside out, replacing them with a filler html config, until you zero-in on which component was causing the failure, then see how much you can put back until the error comes back and you should be looking at only a few remaining lines of configuration that you can eyeball against the docs/samples.

Comment: +1 Simple but effective. Just did this when all other methods didn't work or apply.

Comment: definitely the way to go but its frustrating how somethings that seem to make sense are totally rejected by the layout engine for no apparent reason.  I just got one I narrowed down to adding `  align: 'stretch'` to a hbox.  I dont why that should ever fail

Comment: Sad but true. Too often I need to resort to it with extjs.

Answer (score 4):

I was receiving 'Layout run failure' messages in my app and discovered the problem was caused by forgetting to set the layout property inside of my Viewport.js file.  Once I defined a layout there, everything worked magnificently well. :)

Example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport',{
   extend    : 'Ext.container.Viewport',

   layout  : 'fit',

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of the causes can be attributed as -

1. Overnesting (look for layouts inside layout. Some layout nested combinations will give this error)
2. A container is missing a layout.
3. A container or its children are missing sizing information. For
   example height/width or flex.
4. Using [ui](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-ui) config on a component that is not defined in the sass.

To debug, we should investigate the layouts in the views where the exception is thrown.

Unfortunately, there is no documentation available.

*source: Sencha support*

Comment: Wow! The _"layout nested combinations"_ was the key! Thanks! In my case, a `hbox/stretch` inside a `hbox/stretch` made it fail. I changed the inner for `fit` and worked!